# Detect text inside a box using Google TextRecognizer

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, text-recognition

I am using the Google's "Text[image] Recognizer" to detect text from SurfaceView. all of the code is working very well .. but i want to detect the text in a box similar to what we have in a Barcode Reader .. Please check the image attached.

Comment: Here you can extract an image to a text https://github.com/mahimrocky/TextRecognizer

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales  no i dont want this .. i want something similar to barcode reader ..